# Getting Country, State, City, PostalCode from GPS coods

Tags: geolocation, gps

I am using ipinfodb.com to get geolocation info for IPs, but it only gives postal codes for US addresses.

I am also getting GPS coods from mobile devices, but I need to get more useful information from these GPS coods, that is the country, state, city and postalcode of that GPS coods.

Two questions, 1) is there a more comprehensive database than ipinfodb.com that will get postal codes for IPs outside of the US? 2) is there a way to get address information from GPS coods (including places outside the US).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MaxMind offers a free version of their GeoCity database.

http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity

Also, there is an open source, free-to-use web service at:

http://hostip.info

Both should provide comprehensive location data.

Answer (score 0):

Google does [reverse Geocoding](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding) but IIRC, according to the Terms and Conditions, the results are to be used only in a Google Map.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that as well, I need to for things other than Google Map. Other options? Does Yahoo have something which doesn't have that limitation.

Comment: @cappuccino they do reverse geocoding: http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/maps/classreference/com/yahoo/maps/webservices/geocoder/Geocoder.html but I don't know what their limitations are. It should be possible to find out on their site though